# Return all Matrix blocks with a drop down set to a specified value

Tags: templating, matrix

I'm in the context of an Entry that has a Matrix field, and one of those Matrix fields is a Dropdown called `subsection`. I want to grab all Matrix blocks that have `subsection` set to 'intro'.

This is how I'm trying to do it and it definitely doesn't work. Is there another way to accomplish this?

```
{% for block in entry.myMatrix.subsection('intro') %}
…
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
{% for block in entry.myMatrix if block.subsection == 'intro' %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This displays an error for me: "Internal Server Error

Craft\MatrixBlockModel and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "subsection"."

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your Matrix field? I just want to make sure I'm visualizing it correctly.

Comment: Tyler: Here is a [screenshot](http://cl.ly/image/1H0x1H3J0L1k). I made some of the names more generic than my actual case (obviously I don't call my Matrixes "myMatrix"!) but the scenario is still the same. More realistic code based on this screenshot would be `{% for block in entry.approachBlurb if block.subsection('team') %}`

Comment: I replicated your setup and tested against block.subsection == 'research'. I updated my answer with a functioning conditional :) Let me know if this still doesn't work for you.